# using Google Apps Script in Google Form for checking existing data in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

There is one field in a Google Form that should have a unique value in the form response's spreadsheet.  How can I tell the user whether the value already exists?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to manually update the [advanced validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en) using a regular expression, before the user opens the Form, to allow the value to pass or not. [Issue 4216](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4216) is a request to access that validation via scripts. Star that to vote for it.

Comment: Thank you.  I submit [Issue 5651](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5651) to google.

Comment: a new duplicate issue isn't needed, just star the existing one